# Matching the Json schema with the response getting from the API in rest-assured

Tags: json, rest, automation, rest-assured, rest-assured-jsonpath

I have a post API , i want methods of JsonSchemaValidator to be used as I want the whole reponse to be validated rather than selected reponse by performing assertion

I have tried to use

1. matchesJsonSchemaInClasspath("my file name") and
2. matchesJsonSchema(my file object)

my reposne is coming to be true, method is getting passed but there is no checking or validation with my schema file

```
public void directLoginWihSchemaValiadtor(){
    File file = new File("C:/Users/abeey/git/SlingAppWebService/Configurations/JsonSchemaValidator_DirectLogin_AWS.json");
    jsonasmap.put("contactNo", "some number");
    jsonasmap.put("loginType","0");
    jsonasmap.put("appid","2");
    jsonasmap.put("co*****ode","IN");
    JsonSchemaFactory jsonSchemaFactory = JsonSchemaFactory.newBuilder().
    setValidationConfiguration(ValidationConfiguration.newBuilder().freeze()).freeze();

    given().contentType(ContentType.JSON).body(jsonasmap).when().
    post("https://60i*****.execute-api.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/some-api").
    then().assertThat().
    body(JsonSchemaValidator.matchesJsonSchema(file))).


    log().all();
    jsonasmap.clear();
}
```

//body(JsonSchemaValidator.matchesJsonSchemaInClasspath("JsonSchemaValidator_DirectLogin_AWS.json").using(jsonSchemaFactory))

I tried  to use jsonSchemaFactory to do this but i didnt get that either on what to set as the draftversion or from where to get it

I am new to this , please bear with me if you found this question too simple to be asked

Comment: Try specifying which schema draft you want to use when creating your `JsonSchemaFactory`. `DRAFTV4` is what I use.

Comment: i have used that and it doesn't work and I think it is used to only check that the json response is of DraftV4 version

Comment: Can you post the schema you are validating?

Comment: this is the code that I have created using  JsonSchemaFactory  


 JsonSchemaFactory jsonSchemaFactory = JsonSchemaFactory.newBuilder().
  setValidationConfiguration(ValidationConfiguration.newBuilder().setDefaultVersion(SchemaVersion.DRAFTV4).freeze()).freeze();


given().contentType(ContentType.JSON).body(jsonasmap).when().post("https://***d.execute-api.us-***-*.amazonaws.com/some-api").then().assertThat().body(JsonSchemaValidator.matchesJsonSchema(file).using(jsonSchemaFactory)).log().all();


If you have any suggestions on improving it so the result could be acheived please tell

Comment: the question is whatever I am putting in schema whether its correct or incorrect , it doesn't matter

it will show pass anyway

Comment: Then it is a false positive. I just tried on one of my tests with just `{}` in a test.json file returned a passed test. So it seems if schema is incorrect that you are trying to validate against, you will get a pass when it should be a fail

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For such case usually I do following:

1. use schema generator and create the schema for json body (I use this tool [json-schema-generator](https://www.npmjs.com/package/json-schema-generator))
2. put generated json schemas in the classpath (for example test/resources)
3. use this code as part of REST Assured test:

   .body(matchesJsonSchemaInClasspath("your_schema_name.json"))

If you want to make sure that schema validation is working, you can edit schema file and change the type of any required field to something else and see that your test will fail.

You can refer to [this post](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-extract-values-when-api-testing-with-rest-assured) of mine to see some code samples.

Comment: Sadly I was writing mine by hand for the last few weeks. Didnt think to check for tools to do a schema for you. I found this one: https://jsonschema.net/#/editor

Comment: there are plenty of tools indeed, I stacked to one I mentioned, cause it is very easy to install, do not require configuration and do the job really good, using it already year or so in lots of tests

Comment: thank you so much @BigGinDaHouse 
I was writing myself the schema it was not in the correct order 
so may that can be the reason I was not getting any validation for that 
Thanks a tonne